# Is there a way to register a call-back method/code-snippet with assert in pytest (python)?

Tags: python, pytest

I would like to define custom functions say foo() and bar().
I'd like to register foo(), bar(), etc. with assert such that when assert is invoked, these methods should be called. Also, would it be possible to invoke the call-back based on a condiftion (say if assert evaluates to True)?

Thanks
Sharad

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Actually, looking further into your question, maybe you want something like this - implementing your own `pytest_assertrepr_compare` and calling `foo` and `bar` based on that:
https://pytest.org/latest/assert.html#defining-your-own-assertion-comparison

```
# content of conftest.py
from test_foocompare import Foo
def pytest_assertrepr_compare(op, left, right):
    if isinstance(left, Foo) and isinstance(right, Foo) and op == "==":
        return ['Comparing Foo instances:',
                '   vals: %s != %s' % (left.val, right.val)]

# content of test_foocompare.py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.val == other.val

def test_compare():
    f1 = Foo(1)
    f2 = Foo(2)
    assert f1 == f2
```

Original answer below:

Since assertions would raise an exception, you could try something like

```
try:
    assert(whatever)
except AssertionError as e:  # Or whatever other exception you expect
    foo()                    # Call your function
    raise e                  # Reraise to make your test fail
```

Comment: Thanks. But pytest_assertrepr_compare is called only when the assert fails.

Comment: What about defining your own helper assert method that first calls foo or bar, and then calls pytest assert?

Comment: Yes I thought of that approach as well. Thanks. But with that, I lose the capability of pytest's tracing for failed asserts (pytest gives a nice traceback of which assert has failed). Even though it'll work, but it'll always show the helper method in the traceback and not the actual code that intended to invoke assert.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [`pyhamcrest`](https://github.com/hamcrest/PyHamcrest) instead of internal py.tests `assert`. So it possible to just reimplement [`assert_that`](https://github.com/hamcrest/PyHamcrest/blob/master/src/hamcrest/core/assert_that.py) method with your hooks or something else.

Comment: Sergey Voronezhskiy: Thank you!